# AWS Encrypt connection between LoadBalancer and EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

It is my infrastructure:
Frontend (SSL certificate) -> HTTPS requests -> AWS LoadBalancer (SSL certificate implemented) -> HTTP requests -> EC2 Instances (Elastic Beanstalk).

What is the best way to secure the connection between LoadBalancer and EC2 Instances?

Answer (score 0):

For that you would have to setup self-signed SSL certificate between your EB and EC2.

The ElasticBeanstalk documentation has entire section dedicated to this:

- [Configuring end-to-end encryption in a load balanced Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html):

> You must also configure the instances in your environment to listen on the secure port and terminate HTTPS connections. The configuration varies per platform. See Configuring your application to terminate HTTPS connections at the instance for instructions. You can use a **self-signed certificate** for the EC2 instances without issue.